# How to run a PowerShell script from a C# program?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that accepts user inputs as user credentials. It prompts a window asking for a username and password. I want to run this script using C#. How can I do this?

Comment: We are not clairvoyant. Please copy/paste your code into the question as text. Select the code text and use the `{}` icon. Please make a MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a project reference to the `System.Management.Automation` assembly* and `System.Collections.Objectmodel` (for execution output).

You will then need to create a static method for the PowerShell class (Note: PowerShell class implements `IDisposable` so you need to wrap it in a using block):

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
    }
```

Use the add script method `(PowerShellInstance.AddScript())` to add your script.

From there you can execute your script Synchronously or Asynchronously using `.Invoke()` and `.BeginInvoke()` respectfully.

Reference this MSDN Blog here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/